# Sorting by sub document element in bulk

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

I have schema like this :

```
({
  _id:id ,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  name:name,
  friends : [{name:"tommy",children:[{name:"sarah",age:12}]}],
  dogs : [{}]
});
```

where the "name" attribut in friends is actually a number.

I'm updating said array using :

```
  var obj = {name:"tommy",children:[{name:"ds",age:12},{name:"two",age:12}]};
  var bulk = db.t.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  bulk.find({"friends.name":obj.name}).update({$addToSet:{"friends.$.children":{$each:obj.children}}});
  bulk.find({"friends.name":{$ne:obj.name}}).update({$push:{"friends":obj}});
  bulk.execute();
```

I'm trying to make it so that the friends array is always sorted by the " name " attribut in ascending order ( remember it's a number in reality) so that the output array for friends is always sorted :

```
friends : [{name:34,children:[{name:"sarah",age:12}]},{name:38,children:[{name:"sarah",age:12}]},{name:95,children:[{name:"sarah",age:12}]}]
```

As by the [doc example The sort document refers directly to the field in the documents and does not reference the containing array field](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/sort) i've tried adding `$sort: { name: 1 }` but it doesn't do anything and the array is left untouched:

```
  var obj = {name:"tommy",children:[{name:"ds",age:12},{name:"two",age:12}]};
  var bulk = db.t.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  bulk.find({"friends.name":obj.name}).update({$addToSet:{"friends.$.children":{$each:obj.children,$sort: { name: 1 }}}});
  bulk.find({"friends.name":{$ne:obj.name}}).update({$push:{"friends":obj,$sort: { name: 1 }}});
  bulk.execute();
```

can anyone see my mistake ? Is it possible to sort in bulk operations ?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be asking for the `"friends.children"` element to be sorted, but all your `$sort` is being performed on `"friends"`. So which are you really looking to "sort"? As for the first operation `$sort` does not work with `$addToSet` since sets are not considered to be sorted in any way. You either do a `{ "$each": [], "$sort": { "name": 1 } }` afterwards or check that the "child" is not already in the array and use `$push`. Really unclear what you are expecting otherwise. Nested arrays are not a wise design choice FYI.

Comment: Yes you first point didn't seems logical to me either ( and i did "friends.childrens" to begin with since that's what i'm trying to sort) i'm just trying to do what the doc say : The sort document refers directly to the field in the documents and does not reference the containing array field quizzes; i.e. { score: 1 } and not { "quizzes.score": 1}   here : https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/sort/ , so what would that do on the push ( second ) bulk line ?

Comment: I think you sound a little "over excited" in both your question and comments. Maybe take a breath and just try clearly demonstrating some existing content, something to add, and then finally what you expect the end result of the content and addition to be. Then we can explain that process.

Comment: I'm just quoting the doc to answer your very first sentence/question.

Comment: You are being asked to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35840568/edit) your question to make it more clear. We people who can provide answers are a lot more familiar with documentation than you are.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

```
Collection.update({"_id":id},{$push: {"friends": { "$each": [], "$sort": { "name": 1 }}}});
```